# Como acceder a emailAddress dentro de file1['owners'] PyDrive Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con `print(file1['owners']`) imprimo :

```
[{'kind': 'drive#user', 'displayName': 'Nombre Random', 'picture': {'url': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/urlrandom'}, 'isAuthenticatedUser': True, 'permissionId': 'muchosnumerosdeId', 'emailAddress': 'ejemplo@gmail.com'}]
```

Cuestion que quiero capturar solamente el emailAddress
Intente cosas como `file1['owners']['emailAddress']` pero no funciona de esta forma

Comment: Tienes que procurar no poner imágenes para mostrar el código. Eso dificulta que otros usuarios puedan replicar el error y encontrar una solución apropiada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta solucion:
To get the emailAddress of that item it's `file1["owners"][0]["emailAddress"]`